# Padding issues while viewing website with mobile device

Tags: css, mobile, layout, padding

Can someone take a look at my website and help me fix the mobile display. More specifically setting up and fixing the padding and margins.. When i view the website on my Iphone its a mess.

Would like to use CSS to fix the issue as I have researched some help but can't get it to work yet.The main CSS mobile target is below:

```
@media
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

www.jobspark.ca

Comment: I see the padding/margin issues. What you can do is resize your browser since you're using media queries. If you resize the browser you can use a DOM inspector like FireBug or the built-in DOM inspector that comes with Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px){
    #site > .wrapper, #footer > .wrapper {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 40px;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It is starting to look better. I just had one last question. Can you see why on the hompage the two sections called "Used by Canadians" and Mobile job search" didnt resize like the rest of the page. Can you show me how to fix this last part. Thanks again! http://www.jobspark.ca/